# How do I test a Java Code Generator in NetBeans?

Tags: java, unit-testing, netbeans, tdd, netbeans-platform

I am starting to program a Code Generator for `NetBeans 8`, and I am having trouble figuring out the best way to test its `invoke()` method.

The code generator I want to test is basically like this:

```
(imports here)

public class MyCodeGenerator implements CodeGenerator { 

    private final JTextComponent textComponent; 

    private final CompilationController controller; 

    MyCodeGenerator(final Lookup context) { 
        textComponent = context.lookup(JTextComponent.class); 
        controller = context.lookup(CompilationController.class); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public String getDisplayName() { 
        return "Generate Some Code..."; 
    } 

    /** 
     * This will be invoked when user chooses this Generator from Insert Code 
     * dialog 
     */ 
    @Override 
    public void invoke() { 
        if (textComponent != null && controller != null) { 
            controller.toPhase(Phase.RESOLVED); 
            //do more things with the source code; 
        }    
    } 
}
```

I want to use a mocked (Mockito) object for Lookup, to pass to the `MyCodeGenerator`'s constructor. The mock should return the `JTextComponent` and the `CompilationController`.

I know I can provide a `JTextComponent` with the test code, but I hit the wall when I need to provide a `CompilationController`.

I can create a temporary java source file with the same content as the `JTextComponent`, but I could not find a way to create a `CompilationController` (or `WorkingCopy`) from it.

This is what I tried so far (my test method):

```
@Test 
public void testInvoke() throws ParseException, IOException { 
    System.out.println("invoke"); 
    final ExtractControllerTask extractTask = new ExtractControllerTask( 
            Phase.RESOLVED); 
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(100); 
    final JTextComponent textComponent; 
    final Document document; 
    final FileObject javaTestFile; 
    final OutputStream outputStream; 
    final JavaSource source; 

    builder.append("public class Clazz {"); 
    builder.append("private int a = 2;"); 
    builder.append("}"); 

    textComponent = new JTextArea(builder.toString()); 
    document = textComponent.getDocument(); 
    document.putProperty(BaseDocument.MIME_TYPE_PROP, "text/x-java"); 

    javaTestFile = FileUtil.createData(new File( 
            "/tmp/javaTestSourceFile.java")); 
    outputStream = javaTestFile.getOutputStream(); 
    outputStream.write(builder.toString().getBytes()); 
    outputStream.flush(); 

    source = JavaSource.forFileObject(javaTestFile); 
    assertNotNull(source); 
    source.runUserActionTask(extractTask, true); 
    assertNotNull(extractTask.controller); //FAILS HERE 
}
```

This is the code for ExtractControllerTask:

```
private static class ExtractControllerTask implements 
        Task<CompilationController> { 

    private final Phase targetPhase; 

    private CompilationController controller; 

    private ExtractControllerTask(final Phase phase) { 
        this.targetPhase = phase; 
    } 

    public void run(final CompilationController compControler) { 
        try { 
            compControler.toPhase(this.targetPhase); 
            this.controller = compControler; 
        } catch (IOException ioe) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe); 
        } 
    } 

}
```

What surprises me is that the `run` method in `ExtractControllerTask` is never called.

I really need to test my code but I can't find the proper way. Maybe the approach is completely wrong.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Just a guess: Maybe it's not working because the Java source file is not named `Clazz.java` (matching the name of the class in the file).